# The Action of a Linear Transformation $T$ on a subspace.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, definition

Problem Statement:

Let $T:V\rightarrow V$ be a linear transformation. The following are equivalent:

($i$)

$\exists \mathcal{B}=\{v_1,...,v_n\}\subset V$ such that 
$$[T]_\mathcal{B}=\begin{pmatrix}
    \lambda_1 & 0 & \dots & 0 \\
    0 & \lambda_2 & \dots & 0 \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
    0 & 0 & \dots & \lambda_n
  \end{pmatrix}$$

($ii$)

$\exists u_1,...,u_k\in \mathbb{F}$ and subspaces $V_1,...,V_k$ of a Vector Space $V$ such that $V=\bigoplus^{k}_{1}V_i$, and $\forall i\in \{1,...,k\}$
the action of $T$ on $V_i$ is given by multiplication by $u_i$.

---

I only need clarification. My Problem is that I do not understand what "the action of $T$ on $V_i$ is given by multiplication by $u_i$" means. Does it mean that if $v_i\in V_i$, then $T(v_i)=u_iv_i$?

My professor did not define what it means and it doesn't seem absolutely clear from the context.

Oh, and $[T]_\mathcal{B}$ is the matrix representation of the linear transformation $T$

Comment: yep, that is what it means, or more nicely written: $T\mid_{V_i}=u_i id_{V_i}$